# Pass a (sorted) std::vector to a method

Tags: c++

Consider the following scenario:

```
class A
{
public:
    void FunA()
    {
        auto v = std::vector<int>();
        // Fill the vector
        B().FunB(v);
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    void FunB(const std::vector<int>& v)
    {
        // ...
        std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
        // ...
        // call std::binary_search() on v
    }
};
```

In `FunB`, I just want to use `v` to search its contents, hence I want to pass it as a `const &` so that it is clear that I don't intend to modify it. But `std::sort()` won't work on `const std::vector`.

Possible solutions:

1. Remove the `const` -> That'd intend that `v` may be modified within `B::FunB()` which is not the case.
2. Always expect a sorted `v` when passed to `B::FunB()` -> This can only be done via writing a comment and hoping the caller reads it. If he doesn't, the behavior changes!

What should be the correct way to approach this?

Comment: Make your own class sorted_vector which implements this logic wrapping the vector.

Comment: you can't sort the const vector , you can use another vector and copy values of vector on that. then sort that vector

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk That'd involve making a copy of the vector. And I'd love to avoid that since it is going to be large.

Comment: @CinCout You can't both sort the vector and not sort it. You could use `std::is_sorted` to determine whether the input is sorted and assert or throw an exception if it isn't, or create your own type that is always sorted. There's also the possibility that a vector is not the appropriate structure for solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the last part @molbdnilo. `std::set` will also do the job. XY-problem it is!

Comment: Maybe change `FunB` to expect a `std::set`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the two possibilities you've presented aren't exhaustive. Why not simply copy the vector? The change is trivial:

```
void FunB(std::vector<int> v)
```

And everything will work fine. If it's not absurdly big, the time cost of copying will be negligible compared to sorting, if you can spare the added memory usage.

---

I've noticed in comments that you've mentioned that the vector is going to be large. Still, this remains a viable option for a lot of cases.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which takes a vector by reference and stores a reference to that class.
In the constructor it can do anything You want, for example sort the vector.

Then the function in class B should take this new class by copy. So a temporary object will be created (calling the constructor which takes a vector) which will store the vector by reference. As a side-effect it will sort it.

Then You can freely binary search it or ...

Add the binary_search into the new class.

```
class Vector_Sorter
{
public:
    std::vector< int >& Vector;
    Vector_Sorter(std::vector< int >& vec) 
        : Vector(vec) 
    {
        std::sort(Vector.begin(), Vector.end());
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    void FunB(Vector_Sorter v)
    {
        // ...
        // ...
        // call std::binary_search() on v.Vector
    }
};

class A
{
public:
    void FunA()
    {
        auto v = std::vector< int >();
        // Fill the vector
        B().FunB(v);
    }
};
```